# How to allow a customer website to interact with my website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My MVC app allows a user to create interviews.  Now, in order for a user to conduct an interview, they can interact with my website to start the interview.  But I also want to provide a mechanism that allows my users to start an interview from THEIR OWN WEBSITE.

So, my app assigns each interview a unique string identifier the my customers can view (via a secure webpage).  My plan is to have an HTTPS URL to which my customer can POST, with POST data that includes the identifier of the interview they want to start, plus some ancilary data telling me how to deliver the interview results back to them. (Including the data in the POST data allows the HTTPS magic to secure the data from prying eyes - I hope.)

This scheme was dreamed up entirely by a guy with zero practical web programming experience (that would be me), so I'd like to solicit feedback from folks who actually know how to do this sort of thing.  Is there a "standard" way to do this sort of thing?  Sort of like how websites head off to PayPal?

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a sort of script (javascript) that renders an iFrame that holds some view from your web app in ASP.NET MVC.

That way, the website of your customer don't need to be in a given technology.

Check the way [ECWID](http://www.ecwid.com/) is integrated in other websites... using just some HTML/JS code.

Comment: Cool.  Up till now I've been concentrating on just coming up to speed on basic Web technology (HTML, MVC, controllers, views, partial views, child actions...).  I guess it's time to start digging into the world of Javascript and AJAX.  I've seen plenty of examples of AJAX, but they all assume a basic level of web savvy that I don't yet have.  Oh well, this is another good excuse to use that expensive Safari Books Online subscription that I paid for.